# Logging duplicate messages once

Tags: java

I'm in a unique situation where I am receiving duplicate messages from 10-25 sources at the same time or at nearly the same time. The code I came up to counter this was:

```
private Queue<String> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

public void log(String message) {
    if(!messages.contains(message)) {
        if(messages.size() >= 5) {
            messages.remove(0);
        }
        messages.add(message);
        Main.getLogger().info(message);
    }
}
```

The problem with this code is that since the method is being called concurrently, it will sometimes log messages 2-4 times instead of only once.

Comment: What is the significance of `if(messages.size() >= 5)` ?

Comment: Sometimes, messages like 'Data received' are logged at different intervals. Without keeping the size down, it will only log 'Data received' once.

Comment: this is a check-then-act issue, you have to hold the lock across the if-test and the resulting action.

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting the actual writes to the logger in a separate thread that reads the incoming log messages from a thread safe queue and checks for duplicates just before writing. Your apps that perform logging would simply write the log messages to the queue and the writer would monitor the queue for new messages. When a message comes in, it's checked for uniqueness against some number of previous messages and if it is unique, it's both written to the queue and stashed in the set of older messages to check against (potentially pushing out an older message).